# can't create many to many relationship between Account and Product

Tags: account, master-detail, junction-object, product

Product is not showing up in the object list when I am trying to create a master-detail relationship from my junction object.

what's the workaround?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Product can show up as Product2 in the API interface. The Product2 object does not actually support being set as the Master in an M;D relationship,but I can't find any specific Salesforce documentation that addresses this.

You can always use a Lookup relationship instead of a Master-Detail. There is a limit of 2 Master Detail relationships on a specific custom object so that may be blocking you, otherwise the following may apply:

> You can't create a master-detail relationship if the custom object already contains data. You can, however, create the relationship as a lookup and then convert it to master-detail if the lookup field in all records contains a value.

[Relationship considerations](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=relationships_considerations.htm)

This previous [question and answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/33554/why-cant-i-create-a-master-detail-relationship-between-product-and-my-custom-ob) may also help.